# Create action in module's controller in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, controller, zend-tool

I have `Group` module and `Moderator` controller in my zend project on ubuntu. My Controller class is like this:

```
class Group_ModeratorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
 -------
 -------
}
```

When I try to create action delete in Moderator controller or Group module like this:

```
zf.sh create action delete moderator 1 group
```

It gives my following error:

```
An Error Has Occurred                         
Controller Moderator was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem myself before, try this:

```
zf.sh create action delete Moderator 1 -m group
```

The *1* may not be required I'm pretty sure the default is to create the view.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
zf.sh create delete moderator 1 group
```

Comment: try this just to see what happens zf.sh create test moderator 1 group

Comment: Provider 'delete' is not a valid provider.